# Strange htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Whats is wrong with my htaccess here..

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
RewriteRule ^page somepage.php [L]
```

Im try redirect http://mysite.com/somepage.php to http://mysite.com/page and this working fine, but i can also access to this url `http://mysite.com/page2121` or `http://mysite.com/pageasd4a4sd` ... and all is redirected to same page somepage.php, what is wrong here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the $ at the end of page like the following:

> RewriteRule ^page$ somepage.php [L]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean redirect `/page` to `/somepage.php`, you need to explicitly set the end of the pattern, write now, yours is matching everything that starts with `page`, not starts and ends with `page`. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page$ somepage.php [L]
```

(the `$` is key)